# java Global global variable and user global variable

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm using a spring mvc controller with annotation. The app is build in two part. The first one manages the users personal session and the other manages global data (shared between users).

The controller code is like that:

```
....
//******Global variables: For every user !!!******
private String serverName = "myServer";
...

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("Login")

..
public boolean validateUser(@Valid Login login){
if (login.userExist)
{
// continue app
// ***Here I would like a "global variable" but only for THIS user***
}
else ....
```

As you see in this example, How could I do to have global variables for all users and "global variable" but only for the user session ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to use spring, then there will be a `security context` perhaps? If so, there is the appropriate place for that global variable. Since in every point of the app the context is available.

A java focus would be to create a `Map<String, Set<Object>>` where to store pairs of user and properties. And another one with     class scope.

Comment: This not exactly what I want, as Spring security cover access and session security. This is not exactly my question. In fact it true that it's more a pure java question on how to use global variables for all classes and "global variables" for some class methods only